# How can I ignore the special character in the node?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml where I just want to have the amount exclusive the special character "+".

```
<LegalMonetaryTotal>
<LineExtensionAmount currencyID="EUR">+1848.20</LineExtensionAmount>
<TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="EUR">+1848.20</TaxExclusiveAmount>
<TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="EUR">+2236.32</TaxInclusiveAmount>
<PayableAmount currencyID="EUR">+2236.32</PayableAmount>
```

I have already tried some codes like substring-length etc.. or adding # before my code, but I'm not getting the results I want to get.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="/x:Invoice/cac:LegalMonetaryTotal">
      <xsl:if test="cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount,'##0.00')"/></xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This shows the result +1848,20

I want to get 1848,20 only. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there was always going to be a "+" at the start, then you could do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(substring(cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount, 2),'##0.00')"/>
```

Alternatively, if it might not be there, you could do this

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(translate(cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount, '+', ''),'##0.00')"/>
```

Note, if your existing `xsl:for-each` does not have other code in, you can simplify it to this

```
<xsl:for-each select="/LegalMonetaryTotal/TaxExclusiveAmount">
  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(translate(., '+', ''),'##0.00')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```